# how can i redirect run program command on different server

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have 2 server Linux server (RHEL5). Server1 is running X server where users connect to it with VNC/NX and the other one is for running programs.

So users don't interrupt to each other, I want to redirect, for example:

Matlab if some of the users run Matlab on the X server, its redirect the command to the second server Automatically?

I will appreciate for help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to `/etc/profile.d/matlab.sh` on the first server:

```
matlab() { ssh secondServer command matlab "$@"; }
```

Then, when you run

```
matlab foo
```

you'll be running on the other machine.

For convenience, set up ssh keys for password-less login:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id secondServer
```

Comment: it can be working with programs with GUI for example: firefox, emacs, gvim?

Comment: Thanks, its really helpful i add the -X to the ssh command and the GUI working with all program that i added: matlab() { ssh -X secondServer command matlab "$@"; }